# How to define Dockerfile environment variable based on another variable?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to do the following, in `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN x=$(some-script-that-calculates-value.sh ...)
ENV PATH "${PATH}:${x}"
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible?

No.

You can calculate the value externally and use `--build-arg`, but typically such scripts are added to `/etc/profile.d` or similar shell startup scripts.